# operator<< overload for vector

Tags: c++, vector, overloading

i tried the following code i found on the net and is perfectly working.

```
template<typename T,typename T2>
std::vector<T>& operator<<(std::vector<T>& v1, T2 t1){
v1.push_back(T(t1));
return v1;
 }
```

but for me the argument t1 must be from type T and not T2.
**so my first question is:** why when i do

```
std::vector<T>& operator<<(std::vector<T>& v1, ***T t1***) //instead of T2 t1
```

i have the following error:
error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::vector >' and 'std::string {aka std::basic_string}')

**my second question** is a ligne 4 of the code:
what does mean T(t1) ?

thanks a lot !

**EDIT:**

thanks for all your answers!

this is the code i was using to test and try to inderstand the function.

```
using namespace std; 

template<typename T>
std::vector<T>& operator<<(std::vector<T>& v1, T t1){
v1.push_back(T(t1));
return v1;
 } 

int main()  {
vector<string> s;
string s2(" hello ");
s << s2 ;
cout<< s[0];
return 0;}
```

so the T is string and v1 is of type vector(String) and t1 is of type String
this is why i was wondering why removing typename T2 from template causes error even if the value_type is string for both

Comment: Please post a complete example of the code that doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide the full error message, not the parts you consider relevant. Also, see [mcve].

Comment: Beware: copy/pasting C++ code you don't understand will lead to catastrophic crashes.

Comment: Replace `T` with an actual type like `int` or `std::string` and you will understand what `T(t1)` means.

Comment: @YSC already copy/pasting, no need to compile? :P

Comment: @YSC yes thanks for the advice that's why i'm trying to understand it from a to z :)

Comment: @molbdnilo edited :) and thanks for question 2 so it's a kind of a cast ?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error with your code. You didn't put the overload in a separate file or something?

Comment: @molbdnilo ney all in the same main.cpp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i tried the following code i found on the net and is perfectly working.

```
template<typename T,typename T2>
std::vector<T>& operator<<(std::vector<T>& v1, T2 t1){
    v1.push_back(T(t1));
    return v1;
}
```

I wouldn't say that works perfectly:

- The function argument `t1` is accepted *by value*, which means a *copy* of the callers value is made.  That's sometimes very inefficient.  C++ has what's called *move semantics* that automates the efficient reuse of values when possible, you can get the benefit like this:

  ```
  template <typename T, typename T2>
  std::vector<T>& operator<<(std::vector<T>& v, T2&& t){
      v.emplace_back(std::forward<T2>(t));
      return v;
  }
  ```
- `<<` already has two common uses: bitwise shifting and output streaming; adding a third one exponentially increases the confusion.  Someone with a `vector<int> v` might assume `v << 3` would bitshift all the existing elements by 3, someone with `vector<string> w` might assume `w << '.'` would append a fullstop to each string currently stored, someone else might hope it creates a string of the existing elements joined by '.'s - all those hopes/expectations are as reasonable as what you're proposing, so anyone reading the client code would have to be open-minded enough to realise the operation is unclear and then dig in to find out what your `<<` function's actually doing.

> but for me the argument t1 must be from type T and not T2. so my first question is: why when i do

```
std::vector<T>& operator<<(std::vector<T>& v1, ***T t1***) //instead of T2 t1
```

Consider `vector<double> v; v << 2;` works even though `2` is an `int` not a `double`.  It wouldn't work without your single template parameter.

> i have the following error: error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::vector >' and 'std::string {aka std::basic_string}')

Your error message is garbled and you haven't (yet) posted your source code, so I can't say what you did wrong there....

Comment: thanks for your answer! here is maybe a dumb question but  in your argument " T2&& t" why do you use double & ?

Comment: @user9446905 you've a great deal to learn. It's dangerous to go alone, take this: [C++: What are move semantics?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3106110/5470596)

Comment: @user9446905: in additiion to YSC's link, it's good to know speciificallly about `&&` - that's called a *forwarding reference* and used too be known as a *universal reference*.  It means the caller can pass a movable value or a non-movable value, and when `std::forward` is used that "movability" will be properly passed on to the `emplace` function so the value will be moved into the vector if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you didn't explicitly ask for it, my crystal ball tells me you'd be interested in [`std::insert_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/insert_iterator). Once an insert iterator is created on a container (vector, array, list, you name it!), you can add items to the container with an assignation syntax:

```
std::insert_iterator<std::vector<double>> ins(data, begin(data));
ins = 0;
ins = 1.f;
ins = 2.0;
ins = '\x03';
ins = 4ULL;
```

Or for a lighter syntax, you can help yourself with [`std::inserter()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/inserter):

```
auto ins = std::inserter(data, begin(data));
ins = /* ... */
```

This inserts `0.0` to `4.0` into the vector `data`. See an exemple of [a complete program online](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/faa7efcb122fe341).

---

Additional tools:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/front_inserter